# Unable to retrieve regex match results - MFC / C++

Tags: c++, regex, mfc, format-specifiers

I am reading an HTML page and trying to retrieve a specific string within it.

I have the following code:

```
    std::string str = test.GetString(); // someString ( the string i have checked it, it's basically an html page )
    std::smatch match;
    std::regex re("0x(\\d|[A-Z]).*0000"); // the pattern I'm searching for
    if (std::regex_search(str, match, re)){
        test = "found"; // found gets printed
    }
    TRACE("%s\n",match[0]); // this outputs some garbage like this '˜ò'
```

I want to print/store the result of the match found but I get some garbage instead.

Disclaimer: I'm new to C++ regex. I might be doing a basic mistake

Comment: For sample code like this, just put the string in the code instead of calling `test.GetString()`. That way it's clear what's being searched.

Comment: I can't put the whole html... It's tooo long

Comment: Okay, but try and put in a shorter string that shows the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> std::smatch match;
> ...
> TRACE("%s\n",match[0]); // this outputs some garbage like this '˜ò'
> ```

The **`%s`** type specifier in the `TRACE` macro expects a **raw C string pointer** (`char*` in ANSI/MBCS builds; `wchar_t*` in Unicode builds - I'm assuming you are doing an ANSI/MBCS build here.).

But `match[0]` is *not* a raw C string pointer.

So you have a mismatch between what you promised to `TRACE` via `%s` (i.e. a raw C string `char*` pointer), and what you are *actually* passing to it (i.e. `match[0]`).

According to [some online documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results), `std::smatch` is a specialization of the `std::match_results` template, in particular:

```
smatch --> match_results<string::const_iterator>
```

`smatch::operator[]` (which you are invoking in your code as `match[0]`) [returns a reference to another object](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results/operator_at), which is a `std::sub_match`.
This [`std::sub_match` class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/sub_match) represents a pair of iterators, denoting sequences of matched characters.

So, you are *promising* to `TRACE` to pass a raw C string pointer (via the `%s` type specifier), but you are actually passing a *completely different thing*, i.e. a reference to a `std::sub_match` object (via your `match[0]` code): no wonder that the printed text is meaningless.

**What you have to do is to obtain a C string pointer from the `match[0]` expression.**

To do that, you can invoke the [`std::sub_match`'s **`str()`** method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/sub_match/str). This returns a **`std::string`** object.

However, this `std::string` object is *not* exactly what `%s` expects: in fact, `%s` represents a raw C string pointer (e.g. `const char*`), *not* a `std::string` instance.

So, the last step is to extract this raw C string pointer from the `std::string` object, and this is done by invoking the [`std::string::c_str()` method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str).

To summarize these logical steps:

```
std::smatch match;
...
match[0]               --> reference to std::sub_match object
match[0].str()         --> std::string object
match[0].str().c_str() --> raw C string pointer (const char*)
```

So, your `TRACE` statement can be written as:

```
TRACE("%s\n", match[0].str().c_str());
```

Comment: Wow, This is the perfect answer! I understand it completely now and I want to hug you! Thank you so much for this!

Comment: Just wondering, can I tell `TRACE` to expect a `std::string`? instead of `%s`

Comment: @Rana: No, because `TRACE` is based on **C-style** `%s`, instead `std::string` is a **C++ class**, not a C-style raw string pointer. There is no implicit "conversion" from `std::string` to `%s`: you must call the `std::string`'s **`c_str()`** method to get the C-style `const char*` from the `std::string` object (and pass it according to `%s`).

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `match[0]` returns an object of type `sub_match`, which is simply a pair of iterators. If that first argument to the TRACE macro is a C-style format specifier, convert the `sub_match` object to a C string like this:

```
TRACE("%s\n", std::string(match[0]).c_str());
```

That is, use `sub_match`'s `operator string()` to get a (temporary) C++ string object, then call its member function c_str() to get a (temporary) C string object.

Comment: Even though it works, i'm not sure what is going on. could please explain a bit more?

Comment: I have checked the value of `match[0]` in the debugger and it has a value of `157`. What does this represents, the object id number?

Comment: I have no idea what that value means. It sounds like the debugger is confused. `std::match_results` is, more or less, an array of `sub_match` objects. `match[0]` is a `sub_match` object that points to the text that matched all of the regular expression. That is, it holds a pair of iterators; the first points at the start of the matched sequence, and the second points past-the-end of the matched sequence. So you could construct a `string` object like this: `std::string m(match[0].first, match[0].second);`. It's easier to use the conversion operator that `sub_match` provides.

Comment: that makes sense. last question (thank you soo much for your time). Why use the `c_str` after?